# Are there any standard protocols to transfer medical data?

Tags: networking, protocols, medical

Hello Every one

I'm currently working on a project that takes data from patients monitors and send them to another system that we built (Not the central station -which display all monitors- which is already working but it is closed source.).

The monitor is supplied with an Ethernet card and it sends data over the UDP protocol. But when we need to read real data which is in the application layer we understand nothing.

Here is a small frame we get from the traffic when the monitor talks to the central station.

`0000   ff ff ff ff ff ff 66 76 84 00 18 73 08 00 45 00
0010   00 2e 00 00 40 00 40 11 7a 03 c0 a8 00 14 ff ff
0020   ff ff a4 10 1f 42 00 1a 04 45 ff d0 00 02 00 fe
0030   00 0a 32 01 02 03 04 05 0b 32 33 50`


When I but it on wireshark it analyze until the UDP protocol and stop, it doesn't understand the application layer data.
Here is a sample application layer data.

`ff d0 00 02 00 fe 00 0a 32 01 02 03 04 05 0b 32 33 50`


Another one:

`ff da 7f f1 00 04 00 0c 02 18 0d 0f 60 0c 04 0b 0b 10 00 00`

Are there any standard protocols that used in medical field to transport data like ECG, respiration, etc.? And is there a protocol that is compatible with the form above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please stop there!

Get the specification or documentation from the vendor and do not reverse engineer the protocol. If you are unable to do so, leave this thing alone.

If you get it wrong you are endangering patients. Doctor may rely on your information which you are guessing as it seems.

Even if it something well documented like HL7 oder DICOM read the documentation and talk with the vendor.
Depending on jurisdiction there may be a myriad of legal problems ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not reverse engineering any thing, I'm just asking is the data above belong to a particular protocol that I don't know?

Comment: I am not going to split hairs here, but what you do matches exactly the definition of reverse engineering (of protocols): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering 
However: The frames look too short for hl7. No MLLP framing. No HL7.

Answer (score 1):

It may be transmitting in HL7

http://www.hl7.org/index.cfm